# File input on change in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Using plain HTML/JS, it is possible to view the JavaScript File objects of selected files for an input element like so:

```
<input type="file" id="input" multiple onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```

However, when converting it to the 'Vue' way it doesn't seem to work as intend and simply returns `undefined` instead of returning an Array of File objects.

This is how it looks in my Vue template:

```
<input type="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input" 
  v-on:change="previewFiles(this.files)" multiple>
```

Where the `previewFiles` function is simply the following (located in methods):

```
  methods: {
    previewFiles: function(files) {
      console.log(files)
    }
  }
```

Is there an alternate/correct way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `this.files` to point to in your Vue example?

Comment: `this.files` should be an Array of File objects, as it is in the pure HTML example, as seen here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Another solution:

```
<input type="file" @change="previewFiles" multiple>

methods: {
   previewFiles(event) {
      console.log(event.target.files);
   }
}
```

Comment: event is undefined in firefox

Answer (score 83):

Try this.

```
<input type="file" id="file" ref="myFiles" class="custom-file-input" 
  @change="previewFiles" multiple>
```

and in your component options:

```
data() {
  return {
    files: [],
  }
},
methods: {
  previewFiles() {
    this.files = this.$refs.myFiles.files
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For all the TS-Users out there:

```html
<template>
<input ref="upload"
       type="file"
       name="file-upload"
       multiple=""
       accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
       @change="onUploadFiles">
</template>
```

```js
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({ components: {} })
export default class MediaEdit extends Vue {

private onUploadFiles(event: InputEvent): void {
    const files: ReadonlyArray<File> = [...(this.upload.files ? this.upload.files : [])];

        files.forEach((file) => {
            console.log(`File: ${file.name}`);
        });
    }

    /** Upload element */
    private get upload(): HTMLInputElement {
        return this.$refs.upload as HTMLInputElement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<form ref="form">
   <input type="file" @change="previewFiles" multiple tabindex="-1">
</form>

methods: {
   previewFiles(event) {

      // process your files, read as DataUrl or upload...
      console.log(event.target.files);

      // if you need to re-use field or drop the same files multiple times
      this.$refs.form.reset() 

   }
}
```

On Safari, you might face an issue when `@input/change` event won't fire.

`tabindex="-1"` - it's a magic trick to make it works on Safari (13.0.2)