# v-model not compatibile with input file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I can't put a v-model in input tag with type="file", are there any good options to fix that?
This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<input v-model="imageReference" type="file" name="file"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File input on change in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179061/file-input-on-change-in-vue-js)

Comment: Are v-on and v-model same things?

Answer (score 2):

Using v-model makes no sense as you can't set a value on a file input - therefor there is no two way binding here

Just use v-on:change

```
<input id="image" v-on:change="onFileChange" type="file">
```

and define a method like

```
onFileChange(e) {
  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  console.log(files);
},
```