# trying to capture only image name instead of complete image path

Tags: html, vue.js

This is my code where I am trying to achieve while we upload an image the images are displaying with complete path but my requirement is to display only the uploaded image name instead of complete path. And also i am facing this error "Error compiling template:
:
File inputs are read only. Use a v-on:change listener instead. please help me to solve this in vue.js"

```
<template id="step2" v-if="currentStep == 2">
    <input type="file" name="image_p" v-model="step2.image_p" accept="image/*" id="id_post_image">
    <input type="file" name="image2_p" v-model="step2.image2_p" accept="image/*" id="id_post_image2">

    <input type="file" name="image3_p" v-model="step2.image3_p" accept="image/*" id="id_post_image3">
    <input type="file" name="image4_p" v-model="step2.image4_p" accept="image/*" id="id_post_image4">

    <button type="button" @click.prevent="stepsback(2)">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" @click.prevent="goToStep(3)">Next</button>
</template>
```

**vue.js**

```
Vue.component('step2', {
template: '#step2',
props: [
'currentStep',
'step2'
]
});

var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
currentStep: 1,
step2: {
image_p: '',
image2_p: '',
image3_p: '',
image4_p: '',
},
}),
```

Comment: You can use `:model` on `input:file`. This will most likely solve your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50900809/533976

Comment: Replace `v-model=""` with `@change=""`