# Having problem when pass variable with vue 3 and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I'm coding Nuxt 3 and having the following bug

my function,

```js
const checkFileSize = (file: File): boolean => {
  if (!file) {
    return true;
  }

  return props.maxSize * 1024 * 1024 >= file.size;
};
```

This function is call when I upload a file.

but when I console log the above file it returns a Proxy object and because of that I can not read `file.size` . The `file.size` return undefined

I fixed it into `file.value.size` and it worked but the type error on the function input is wrong (because interface File does not have any `value` key)

So do I have to change the type (In this case File => what?).
Or do I have to call my function somewhere else to get the exactly file: File input

I fixed it into `file.value.size` and it worked but the type error on the function input is wrong (Cuz interface File does not have any `value` key)

***Updated:**

Currently I use this code to call handleChange function, and inside handleChange I call checkFileSize

```
const handleChange = (file: File) => {
     checkFileSize(file)
}

<v-file-input @change="handleChange" />
```

Still the problem of define a type for ref value

Comment: Try changing your file param type to `ref<File>`

Comment: it got errors ['ref' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof ref'?ts(2749) ]

Comment: Is this helpful?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59389885/12962668

Comment: The question lacks the details. It's not because it's a proxy, it's because it's a ref. If you expect `File` then you could pass ref value to it and not a ref itself.

Comment: const handleChange = (file: File) => {} Seems that the handleChange method has a refs input, and I dont know how to declare the type of a refs

Comment: <v-file-input @change="handleChange" />

Answer (score 0):

> it got errors ['ref' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

Use Ref to fix type error:

```
const checkFileSize = (file: Ref<File>): boolean => {
  if (!file.value) {
    return true;
  }

  return props.maxSize * 1024 * 1024 >= file.value.size;
};
```